# Change label many JButtons in Java Swing GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton

My problem is I want to change many JButton's labels (may be over 10 or more buttons btw). Is there anyway to use loop to do that?. 
For example: I have 10 buttons is numbered 0 - 9. I want to change the label of buttons from 11 - 20 (Not changing each property one by one of course :) ).
Thank you and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Keep an array `JButton[]`or `List<JButton>`.Itjust might be a case for a JTable if you have similar rows.

Comment: Store them in an array, loop over the array of buttons. You will need some way to get the correct label for each button; it isn't clear where you have the desired label values.

Comment: Thank you guys I found this putting in a List is useful way to change a group of GUI objects. Not only buttons. Many thanks!

Comment: @HungTuan please post your solution as the answer to this question and mark the question answered when you can

Answer (score 0):

The answer is put buttons into an array, create a new array to store numbers. Use loop to add each number to each button.